# Get centralized registry of the user's online accounts from iphone device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, security

Is that possible to get all email Ids of user currently logged in to his device.
I am trying to achieve the same thing `Android Account Manager` class dose.

Is there any way to achieve this?
If yes then as this seems security hole, will apple approve this kind of functionality?

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController class does not provide any function to get mail list setup by user.